# Nothing happens when I use "Open with" and navigate to the file to open with unless I restart explorer.exe

Tags: windows-10

See https://streamable.com/efbzho. The file will not open until I restart explorer.exe; however, it works fine if I run it by doubling clicking or using the open with menu without navigating to the file. This happens with all my file extensions (not just txt) and with other files used to open with (not just Sublime Text). I have tried running DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth and sfc /scannow and restarting my computer but that did not fix it.

Update:
The exact same situation occurred in safe mode, so it is not being caused by an external service or program; however, the problem did not occur when I created a new user profile and tested it on that. Is there a way to fix the problem without transferring everything over to a new profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by the SYSTEM group not having permissions to my user profile in C:\Users. I had previously ran the [takeown command](http://takeown) without the /a parameter. This set me as the only user with permissions to the folder. This was resolved by running the takeown command but this time with the /a parameter. This sets the administrator group as the owner of the folder, which includes the SYSTEM group. Giving ownership to administrators for the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts` key may have also played part.

Comment: You didn't clarify this critical information in the question body, so we could only give guesswork answers. Next time when you ask questions, be sure to state all pertinent facts...

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς For me to have stated this information, I basically would have had to known the cause of the problem and if I did, there would be no point of asking this question in the first place. For example, if I took ownership of my user profile a year ago, do you think I would know that information was relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Open with dialog enumerates the application registration from the following registry keys:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\RegisteredApplications

You could check the key value in the following location contains the correct path:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\YOURFILE.EXE\shell\open\command

Search for the application name and the file extension in the registry to see if other entries are possibly corrupted as well.

Comment: I checked HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\sublime_text.exe\shell\open\command and the (default) key seemed correct. The value was "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "%1". I am unsure what to check in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\RegisteredApplications